# Meaning of ## #

Tags: functional-style, slot

While looking for an answer to a different problem, I came across the following example:

```
In[1]:= Array[Plus[##] &, {2,2}] 
Out[1]= {{2,3},{3,4}}
```

Having read through the documentation on `Slot` and `SlotSequence`, I understand the above example. If we think of it as a matrix $M_{ij}$, it takes the two indices and adds them up, $M_{ij}=i+j$. I also understand that it is equivalent to `Array[Plus[#1,#2] &, {2, 2}]`.

I tried making the expression slightly more complicated:

```
In[2]:= Array[Plus[##,#] &, {2,2}] 
Out[2]= {{3,4},{5,6}}
```

which acts as $M_{ij}=(i+j)+i$, or if we replace the last `#` with `#2`, $M_{ij}=(i+j)+j$.

Now, I am really stuck on interpreting:

```
In[3]:= Array[Plus[## #] &, {2,2}]
Out[3]= {{1,2},{4,8}}
```

What is the corresponding expression for $M_{ij}$?

Comment: `FullForm[## #]`

Comment: Thank you, as a beginner in Mathematica, I don't use `FullForm` as often as I should...

Comment: Hmm, I think I need to find a place to use `######&` in my code.  (It's perhaps less obvious what this is here than in the frontend...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Plus[## #] &` is the same as `Plus[Times[##, #1]]`, which always computes to the same as the simpler `Times[##, #1]` (because `Plus[x]` is just `x`).

Thus this computes the same as

```
Table[i^2 * j, {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
```